# To mock the object of other class and return the value expected using Junit in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I want to test the below class Sample:

```
public class Sample{
    public boolean sampleMethod(){
        SequenceCreate seq = new SequenceCreate();
        .... //Code where seq is used
     }
}
```

The SequenceCreate is another class created as below:

```
 public class SequenceCreate {
      public String nextSeq() {
      SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
      int number = random.nextInt(1000000);
      return String.format("%06d", number);
 }
}
```

My test class as below:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TfaApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleTest{

    @Autowired
    private Sample sample;

    @Mock
    private SequenceCreate seq;

    public void sampleMethodtest(){
          when(sample.nextSeq()).return("123");
          assertTrue(Boolean.True,sample.sampleMethod());
   }
 }
```

This doesnt work. And Assertion Fails. 
By Debugging for hours i found out that the sequence number being generated whenever the method someMethod() is called and not taking the mocked value.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should state which mocking framework you use. also `assertTrue(Boolean.True,sample.sampleMethod());` will always fail, because the first part is a `message` and the second part is boolean condition which has to return either `true` or `false` and you method only returns a string and not a boolean. you would have to do someting like this: `assertTrue("test was successful",sample.sampleMethod().equals("123"));`

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as you are creating the `SequenceCreate` object manually inside the  `sampleMethod()`.

You could make the `SequenceCreate` an instance field and add a public setter os that you can inject that dependency and mock properly:

```
public class Sample{

    private SequenceCreate seq;

    public boolean sampleMethod(){
        .... //Code where seq is used
     }

    public void setSeq(SequenceCreate seq){
       this.seq=seq;
    }
}
```

Then in your test you would do:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TfaApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleTest{

    @Autowired
    private Sample sample;

    @Mock
    private SequenceCreate seq;

    public void sampleMethodtest(){
          sample.setSeq(seq);
          when(seq.nextSeq()).thenReturn("123");
          assertTrue(Boolean.True,sample.sampleMethod());
   }
 }
```

Btw, you were also mocking wrong object. It should be `seq.nextSeq()` used in the `when` method.

Comment: I tried it... but still the seq created is different in the sampleMethod()

Comment: should be thenReturn instead of return. Try again. It also matters whats happening inside sampleMethod method.. as this was not posted

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating this.  First of all you are unit testing Sample, so Spring Boot has nothing to do with it.

Secondly your code is mocking Sample, when you should be mocking SequenceCreate methods.

Make your class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Create a mock of SequenceCreate

```
@Mock
private SequenceCreate seq
```

Create a new instance of Sample

```
@InjectMocks
private Sample sample;
```

Record an expectation of the method you want to mock

```
when(seq.nextSeq()).thenReturn("123");
```

Do your assert.

```
assertTrue(Boolean.True,sample.sampleMethod());
```

Comment: thx for Reply.. i tried this .. but still no luck.. if any of you have good links could you pls share here. i may try to understand.. so i will know if am doing anythign else wrong